# The Galois type:a realization

Tags: set-theory

What does it mean in terms of basic set-theoretic operations in the definition 1.0.25 that $M$ **realizes** $S(N)$ ?
All the relevant definitions are in the snippets, I believe.

As $N\preceq M$ it seems to me that $M$ **always** relaizes $S(N)$ ?
I.e. with $(N,N,a)\in K^3$, say. Here $a$ is any element in $N$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the context here is Abstract Elementary Classes, but actually the question already makes sense even in first-order logic.

We should think of $\operatorname{tp}(a, M, N)$ as the type of $a$ as over the parameters $M$ as computed in the model $N$.  Then the definition of $S(M)$ is that it is the collection of all types over $M$ in all possible elementary extensions of $M$.  The definition of $M$ being full over $N$ is then that every type over $N$ that can be realized in some elementary extension of $N$ is already realized in $M$.

I think the problem here is that the notation is a bit unfortunate - in Definition 1.0.24(2) the $N$ is being universally quantified, so when we later look at $S(N)$ the role of $N$ has changed.  $S(N)$ contains not only types of the form $\operatorname{tp}(a, N, N)$ (that is, types realized in $N$) but also types $\operatorname{tp}(a, N, N')$ for any $N'$ with $N \preceq N'$.

For a concrete example of something not full, in first-order logic it's never true that $N$ is full over $N$ because $N$ never realizes the type $\{x \neq n : n \in N\}$.

Comment: I'm still confused with this issue: in 1.0.24(2) the universally quantified parameter is the **second one but** in your last but one paragraph it becomes the **third one**: $N'$. So you should have written $\operatorname{tp}(a, N', N)$ **or** for any $N'\preceq N$ and then $\operatorname{tp}(a, N, N')$ .

Comment: No, I don't think so.  In the definition the "$M$" is fixed, and the "$N$" varies over all elementary extensions of $M$.  Thus in defining $S(N)$ the "$N$" becomes the second parameter of $\operatorname{tp}(\cdot, \cdot, \cdot)$, which is fixed.  Unless you're referring to Definition 1.0.25, but that's also correct as it's written - in the definition of $M$ being $\lambda^+$-saturated we really do want to say that $M$ is $N$-full for every $N$ with $N \preceq M$.