# Elementary extension considered as a submodel

Tags: logic, model-theory

If we have a model $N$ and its elementary extension $M$, $N\prec M$ can we consider not only $N$ as a submodel of $M$ but **also** vice versa $M$ up to an isomorphic copy $M^*$ a submodel of $N$, $M^*\preceq N$  ; is this observation correct? I have come across this issue in other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961651/the-galois-typea-realization).

I think so because of the snippet below at least if $M$ and $N$ are elementary equivalent and then if $N$ has cardinality $\lambda$ and $M$ cardinality $\lambda^+$ **then** we can view $N^*$ as a submodel of $M$ ? Please see the definition 1.0.25 which should mimic saturation in $\lambda^+$ over $\lambda$.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think such an $N^*$ would exist?

Comment: I have no idea how you think Definition 1.0.25 has to do with your question.

Comment: @EricWofsey Saturation means to try all possible elementary extensions and see if they are realized in the saturated model. But in 1.0.25 the extension $N$ lies in $K_\lambda$ and $M$ in $K_{\lambda^+}$ is fixed which is the reverse mentioned in my OQ.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not true in general.  For instance, $N$ could have greater cardinality than $M$, so there is not even a subset of $M$ of the same cardinality as $N$, let alone an elementary submodule that is isomorphic to $N$.

Comment: Please see my edit.